# How to remove strange white space below the footer of the blog?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have just noticed a strange white space gap below the footer of the blog and about which I don't have any idea, as I haven't touched the CSS or any other part of the code of my blog.

Can anybody tell me how to remove that strange white space?

URL - http://examswatch.com
Let me know if I need to provide any more information?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove margin from line number #5577 (Following code)

```
#masthead {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

**Just a quick tip** you should not put everything in header tag. header tag should contain navigation and logo etc not the entire content. I Think you have missed the closing tag for header.

Comment: you are right, I missed the closing tag for the header. Fixed! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your header There is margin-bottom:60px in your masthead id please remove it and bottom white space will gone. i am attaching screenshot as well for your help.

Hope it will help you.:)[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to share the piece of code that you think is the problem, and you can not just put the website url here. But for your case I checked the style and here is the problem

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 959px)#masthead 
   {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    }
```

You should remove that margin-bottom

Answer (score 0):

The HTML markup is not correct. There are tags which are not closed properly (header tag on line 188) which then results in weird rendering of the HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove: margin-bottom: 60px; 
that is in #masthead, in style.css file.

Answer (score 0):

remove the below css from your code. I don't why are you using this. but this is the issue.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 959px)
#masthead {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```